# How to conditionally process sections in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I have a book I'm generating with `bookdown` where I want to conditionally include a section of a chapter *only when publishing to html* as the section has animations in it.
I can't find documentation on this.
Can someone please point me towards relevant doc?

Comment: Have you tried using `knitr::is_html_output()` to wrap the code in an `if` expression?  I'm having trouble getting PDF books to compile, so I can't be sure right now.

Comment: Thanks; I'll give this a go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the section is in a separate file, you can use `_bookdown.yml` file in the book directory to specify which files to use and which order to compile them depending on rendering format.

```
rmd_files:
  html: ["index.Rmd", "abstract.Rmd", "intro.Rmd"]
  latex: ["abstract.Rmd", "intro.Rmd"]
```

(from [Chapter 1.3 Usage of the bookdown manual](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html))

Comment: Thanks; while this works, I'm wondering if there is a section level toggle to avoid refactoring files, separating animations. This would quickly become unwieldly IMO

Comment: You can conditionally execute code in a code chunk by setting `eval = knitr::is_html_output()` as a chunk option.